# How do I stream a file over 5gb into s3 using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I know I can use transfer manager in java, but I use bash + AWS CLI most the time, and a common task is uploading large files to s3 streaming.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/stdout bs=1 count=0 seek=6G | aws s3 cp - s3://mybucket/myfile
```

How do I get the equivalent of the above to work by using AWS CLI only? Currently it would file as file is over 5gb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this argument:

--expected-size (string)

This argument specifies the expected size of a stream in terms of bytes. Note that this argument is needed only when a stream is being uploaded to s3 and the size is larger than 5GB. Failure to include this argument under these conditions may result in a failed upload due to too many parts in upload.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/cp.html